# Ambiguous Hex/octal value in bitwise operation in C

Tags: c, hex, bitwise-operators, octal

I feel I'm missing something basic about number system but I'm really confused with below piece of code I'm trying to play with bitwise operators:

```
x=56;
printf("\nHere  :\n%x   %x\n",x,077);
x=x& ~077;
printf("%x\n",x);
```

It considers 077 as octal(hex 3f).
And if I put only 77 it treats it as decimal (hex 4d). If put 177 , its treated as decimal(hex b1). I'm referring the book C programming by Richie and Kernighan.

Please help.

Comment: What is question please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All exactly as expected. Start with a 0 and it's octal. Start with 0x and it's hex. Otherwise, it is decimal.

What is the problem?

Comment: Note that in a character constant, `'\177'` is octal, even though there isn't a leading zero.  It is different from what was discussed in the question, but it might be a little confusing.  (You can also have `'\x4D'` for a hex character constant.  More confusingly, you can have `'\x4Dace'` is all a single hex (multi-)character constant with an implementation defined value.)